# Calculating Subtotals for Category Sections Using Class Names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project that is based on an Excel spreadsheet, where I need to calculate budgets, etc. There are various categories in my table, and I need to calculate the subtotal of each category. Here's a screenshot to make it more clear:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVunw.png

My problem is, I'm not sure how to calculate the subtoal for each category. Right now, I have $('.subcat100 .budget').each(function(). The class "subcat100" is attached to the tr and changes for each category section (subcat100, subcat200, subcat300, etc.). The numerical value is based off the sub category number stored in database. How would I pull all of these classes and iterate through them?

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[name="txtQuantity[]"],input[name="txtUnitCost[]"]').change(function(e) {
            var budget = 0;
            var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
            var quanity = $row.find('input[name="txtQuantity[]"]').val();
            var unitcost = $row.find('input[name="txtUnitCost[]"]').val();
            budget = parseFloat(quanity * unitcost);
            var decimal = budget.toFixed(2);
            $row.find('.budget').val(decimal);

            var sum = 0;
            $('.subcat100 .budget').each(function() {
                var budgets = $(this).val();
                console.log(budgets);
                if (IsNumeric(budgets)) {
                    sum += parseFloat(budgets, 10);
                }
            });
            $('.subcat100 .budgetsubtotal').val(sum);
        });

        function IsNumeric(input) {
            return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
        }

    });
```

HTML:

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="subcat100">
                <td>
                    <span name="txtItemCode[]"><strong>100</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td colspan="7">
                    <span name="txtSubCategoryName[]" class="100"><strong>Land Purchase Costs</strong></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="subcat100">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtSubItemCode[]" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="101">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtItem[]" size="50" readonly="readonly" value="Purchase price">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtUnit[]" size="10" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtQuantity[]" class="integer" size="10" value="1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtUnitCost[]" class="monetary" size="10" value="299.99">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtBudget[]" class="monetary budget" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="299.99">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtActual[]" class="monetary" size="10" value="249.99">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtDifference[]" class="monetary difference" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="50.00">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="subcat100">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtSubItemCode[]" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="110">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtItem[]" size="50" readonly="readonly" value="Realtor's fees">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtUnit[]" size="10" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtQuantity[]" class="integer" size="10" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtUnitCost[]" class="monetary" size="10" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtBudget[]" class="monetary budget" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtActual[]" class="monetary" size="10" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtDifference[]" class="monetary difference" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="subcat100">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtSubItemCode[]" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="120">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtItem[]" size="50" readonly="readonly" value="Due diligence">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtUnit[]" size="10" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtQuantity[]" class="integer" size="10" value="15">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtUnitCost[]" class="monetary" size="10" value="45.00">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtBudget[]" class="monetary budget" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="675.00">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtActual[]" class="monetary" size="10" value="700.00">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtDifference[]" class="monetary difference" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="-25.00">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="subcat100">
                <td colspan="5">
                    <span><strong>Subtotal</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtSubTotalBudget[]" class="budgetsubtotal" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtSubTotalActual[]" class="actualsubtotal" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtSubTotalDifference[]" class="differencesubtotal" size="10" readonly="readonly" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up doing this:

```
    var itemcodes = <?php echo json_encode($arrItemCodes);?>;

    $('input[name="txtQuantity[]"],input[name="txtUnitCost[]"]').change(function(e) {
        var budget = 0;
        var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
        var quanity = $row.find('input[name="txtQuantity[]"]').val();
        var unitcost = $row.find('input[name="txtUnitCost[]"]').val();
        budget = parseFloat(quanity * unitcost);
        $row.find('.budget').val(budget.toFixed(2));

        $.each(itemcodes, function(intIndex, objValue) {
            var sum = 0;
            $('.subcat' + objValue + ' .budget').each(function() {
                var budgets = $(this).val();
                console.log(budgets);
                if (IsNumeric(budgets)) {
                    sum += parseFloat(budgets, 10);
                }
            });
            $('.subcat' + objValue + ' .budgetsubtotal').val(sum.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
```

Open to other suggestions!